# Click event dispatches to wrong control

Tags: wpf, event-handling, mouseevent

We have the requirement that on some nondeterministic fired hardware events, depending on the event, the GUI changes. Due to the GUI complexity this may take a few seconds.

Now the problem. If I click on a button while GUI is still busy sometimes the wrong button is invoked because after GUI layouting this button is now at the mouse coordinates where the click occurred before.

Iam sure with Windows Forms the behavior was different. Can I get around this behavior?

Comment: Use background threads to avoid freezing.

Comment: I have this problem also. And not changing out any UI control.  A click down the page causes content above to change (e.g. TextBox bigger or smaller) so the buttons below the mouse is now another button.   Click events fire for both buttons.   Please I hope this gets some traction.  What I had to do is put all buttons at the top so the position would not change but it is a regrets UI.

Comment: I cannot reproduce my problem with a simple sample.  On to problem page I have a frame with a page loaded in code behind and a virtualizing GridView.

Comment: There is not of GUI logic called and executed which calls business logic which calls GUI and so on. So in sum it is extremely slow. Since this is all legacy code I cannot change how it works in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can :

- Hide or cover the UI when it is refreshing (with a [Busy Indicator](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator) for example)
- Optimize the refresh (see [MSDN Wpf Optimization category](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970683.aspx), especially [Layout and design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613542.aspx))
- The quick and dirty - store a IsRefreshing variable and use it to diable the buttons or cancel your buttons handlers

**EDIT**

The real question is : what is your bottleneck ? the UI refresh or the logic behind ?

Comment: How do you disable a UI when it is refreshing?

Comment: With the IsEnabled attribute of an element.

Comment: +1 From your second link  "For example, each time a child UIElement object in the collection changes its position, it has the potential to trigger a new pass by the layout system."  That click firing a second time is a bug.

Comment: I just don't see how IsEnabled could be of use.  On the first click could disable all buttons but then what event would you use to turn buttons back on?

Comment: Ok, I have edited my answer. Forget about the "disable UI" thing, it can only lead to dirty code.

Comment: But you did not edit the answer.  And in my case the hide or cover would not work as both click fire in the same layout.  And I am not criticizing your answer as a whole.  I gave it a +1.

Comment: Well, **I** am criticizing my answer.